# SNMP: OID to use when writing custom MIBs

Tags: snmp

If you are writing your own MIB for a bespoke application, is there a 'best practice' for which branch you should use. I'm thinking of something analogous to private IP addresses, that can be used within enterprises, without conflicting with Registered IP addresses

I have been asked to make a suggestion, as I advised Application Developers that they should not use OIDs under .1.3.6.1.4.1.111 - This is the Oracle branch

Answer (score 12):

For **documentation purposes**, you may use Enterprise Number 32473 (per [RFC 5612](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5612)).  However, to my knowledge, there is no Enterprise Number allocated for purely private use, in the same way that the RFC 1918 IP address space was allocated.  I read one argument in favor of this practice to prevent someone from implementing a private OID numbering for a tool that is then subject to use outside of their network, thus causing conflicts.

Instead, anyone who wishes to implement or use this number space should apply for their own Enterprise Number.  There is no fee associated with it, and it usually only takes a few weeks to process.  Simply submit your application request to IANA, and they'll allocate a number to you.  Of course, before making that request, verify whether you or your company already have a number assigned.  If so, then you should be good to go.  You are free to utilize the branches underneath your Enterprise Number however you wish, so you have a virtually limitless space to work with.

Comment: Good answer! But in the case where your organization already has a number, please contact your MIB branch administrator, like user329633 did. Don't risk calling their wrath down upon you by assigning yourself a branch.

Comment: Yes, I have that noted in my answer: "Of course, before making that request, verify whether you or your company already have a number assigned.". ;-)

Answer (score 11):

I have found that our company has a branch under 1.3.6.1.4.1, which is listed on the IANA website - http://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers

I have advised the application developers that they should contact the person listed with the enterprise number and request to be assigned a leaf node

I'm not sure if whether this approach is what could be considered 'standard' or 'best practice'. I've not found any useful documentation on the subject so far...

Comment: I believe the one you choose is the standard approach. At least, I did the same thing a few years ago for a product.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest following the advice above "verify whether you or your company already ha[s] a number assigned". There is a finite number of enterprise numbers available and unlike the exhaustion of the IPv4 address space, there is no work around.
In my own company (a conglomerate with a number of unrelated divisions), I am going through the process of trying to have the corporation apply for a number but I am under a lot of pressure to get a number for our division only (let each division fight its own battles), presumably because nobody wants to "wake the giant". My point is that if Cisco and HP can do with one number, so should we...

Comment: but, OIDs are encoded as arbitrary length integers, so I don't think we can ever run out of them.

Comment: Enterprise number is a 16 bit value