# how to create OID - Object Identifiers

Tags: monitoring, snmp

I am developing an application which I need to register an OID (Object Identifier) for monitoring purposes. However I am not familiar with OIDs and how to get this created/registered/assigned. Can I create a custom one?

If I have the Company parent OID, would that help in creating custom one? Should be that be registered officially with the certifying authority? could someone help provide some insight on how to create and register an OID?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SNMP: OID to use when writing custom MIBs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744273/snmp-oid-to-use-when-writing-custom-mibs)

Answer (score 2):

You can get a free one instantly [here](https://freeoid.pythonanywhere.com)

This will give you an OID from the branch 1.3.6.1.4.1.54392.4.*

Full disclosure: I created this service.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just create a custom OID yourself, you have to [apply](http://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page) for one. It can take a week or three, but the registration is free. You don't necessarily have to be an organisation - I applied for, and was granted, one for my own personal use a few years ago  without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

There *are* OID branches where you can essentially create your OID without any registration. See [2.25](http://oid-info.com/get/2.25). Simply generate a new UUID/GUID, treat it as a 128-bit number, and use it as an identifier in the subtree.

> UUIDs are octet strings of 16 octets (128 bits) which can be interpreted as an integer that can be used as a child OID of `{joint-iso-itu-t uuid(25)}` **without formal registration** (in particular in this OID repository). This enables users to generate OIDs without registering them with a registration authority.

It however also warns that some software may not support such large OIDs. I have managed to find another branch, [1.2.840.113556.1.8000.2554](http://oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.113556.1.8000.2554) from Microsoft, which uses the individual components instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create any OID you want under your enterprise number. Outside of your enterprise branch, you cannot.
If you want to create one under your enterprise number, you probably need to coordinate with the cognizant individual in your company who is responsible for managing that, but anything under your enterprise number remains totally under your company's purview.