# How to extend my OID existing tree (and write its MIB)?

Tags: snmp

1) How can I extend the OID tree? I would like to have a part of it reserved for my company and that those new OID numbers used by devices manufactured by my company.

2) Once this is done, how can I write a MIB for that new branch of the OID tree? I know the synthax of MIB files, but the problem is how I attach my "custom-MIB-file" to the already existing MIB files. My question is motivated on how Cisco (for example) sell routers with their own OID numbers (and its custom-MIB). How do they do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SNMP: OID to use when writing custom MIBs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744273/snmp-oid-to-use-when-writing-custom-mibs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Regarding generating a dedicated OID branch for your company see :

- [SNMP: OID to use when writing custom MIBs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2744273/449347)

2)  Regarding integration of propriety and standard MIBs/OID trees into a single agent, think them as existing side-by-side rather than being attached to each other, and it being the responsibility of the agent infrastructure to return correct next OID.

The SNMP manager is often supplied with the MIBs (supported by your device) in a off-line step; but you could explicitly list them, see :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25870754/449347