# What snmp trap OID for general purpose application messaging?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jmx, snmp

**Context: Java Application Sending SNMP**

I'm a developer with very little knowledge of SNMP. We wrap our java application with a 'windows service wrapper' which has the ability (among other things) to send snmp messages upon a variety of (user-configurable) events.

The example script has three arguments. Two are well-defined (ip address network monitoring system and "message text").

The other, "OID of the trap" , seems less clear.

By default, the script receives an 'id' parameter then appends it to this value:
"1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.", i.e. so you if you pass in 'id=999', it will broadcast an snmp trap with oid:"1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.999"

Here's a reference for the meaning of "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1." :  it gives a pretty strict meaning as to the body of the corresponding message.

http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.html

> OID value: 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1
>
> OID description:
>
> sysDescr OBJECT-TYPE
>                 SYNTAX  DisplayString (SIZE (0..255))
>                 ACCESS  read-only
>                 STATUS  mandatory
>                 DESCRIPTION
>                         "A textual description of the entity.  This value
>                         should include the full name and version
>                         identification of the system's hardware type,
>                         software operating-system, and networking
>                         software.  It is mandatory that this only contain
>                         printable ASCII characters."
>                 ::= { system 1 }

**Additional Context**

- the application server can expose server info with jmx and products exist to bridge jmx to snmp (i.e. expose amount of memory used, thread count etc). This usecase however is a little different: the java wrapper can send snmp messages based on 'state changes' of the application itself. Developers and admins would find this 'state change' info helpful.
- we're running a few application servers: some in jboss-tomcat, other in plain tomcat
- we're using cacti for the 'snmp receiving' side. I personally don't know if it can handle any 'arbitrary application messages'. I'm assuming it/we would log the messages in a mysql database (or similar) for later querying/reporting.

**Resources**

I've looked around and found resources such as this one (https://github.com/waynearmorize/drivesploit/tree/master/data/snmp/mibs) which lists the various 'pre-defined' OID's. I see a list of values for rdbms-related problems, but no generic "insert your application here".

**Questions**

- Should the developers-and-sysadmins simply come up with our own list of 'application id suffixes': i.e. "1" is "application starting" "2" is application abort "3" is "out of memory" etc, and append this value to the '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.'
- What are the rules? both "hard rules" (i.e. you will break it) and "soft" , 'keep these for consistency'?
- So what are the rules for 'making up' OID's?
- Is SNMP the right tool for the job? It sounds good  to the newbie, but I may be missing something.
- Any tips for this particular realm (i.e sending snmp traps from applications )?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> - Should the developers-and-sysadmins simply come up with our own list of 'application id suffixes': i.e. "1" is "application starting" "2"
>   is application abort "3" is "out of memory" etc, and append this value
>   to the '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.'

Every OID has a globally unique purpose and meaning. For example, OID *1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2* is defined in [SNMPv2-MIB](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3418). The numbers break down as *iso(1).org(3).dod(6).internet(1).mgmt(2).mib-2(1).system(1).sysObjectID(2)*.

You can look up the meaning of selected (by Cisco) OIDs using the [Cisco SNMP Object Navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do). Note that there is no requirement for all MIBs to be published so there's no central collection where you can look up an arbitrary OID. You can think of a MIB as a document for defining OIDs, their types and relationships. A MIB has a formal, machine parseable structure.

Organisations often request a [Private Enterprise Number](http://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page) and then define their stuff under OIDs begining with *1.3.6.1.4.1.PEN*. If you can't find a published standard that meets your use case you may want to do this.

---

From a purely technical point of view, you can issue a trap with any OID at all but this will defy the expectations of anyone analysing the received value.

Comment: Specifically regarding the top level OID that the new product will use, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744273/snmp-oid-to-use-when-writing-custom-mibs